# How to insert data into the database file which is in the assets folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I have created a SQLite file and putted it on to assets folder. Now I am able to read the data from that file but I don't have any idea how to write to this database file. I need to take the user name and score and store that in to that database file. I searched on the web and on the SO also but there are examples for the normal database insertion.

Can any one tell me how to store the values into database file. I need to store the username and score. Just think this to as Strings and please give me a example for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not create database in the assets folder as we can only read data from assets folder.

Infact you should create the database in the default internal folder i.e **data/data/[package-name]/databases**   OR  you also can create your database in the sdcard and can perform read-write operation but of course it will not run if there is no sdcard.

The following is the code for creating databse in sdcard:-

```
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static Context cntxt;

    public static File filename = null;
    public static String DATABASE_FILE_PATH_EXTERNAL = null;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,1);
            cntxt = context;
            try{
                try{
                    filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(DbHelper.cntxt, "Please Insert SD card To create Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Log",e.getMessage(),e.fillInStackTrace());
                }

                DATABASE_FILE_PATH_EXTERNAL = filename.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+DATABASE_NAME;

                //  db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH_EXTERNAL, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE + SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            }catch(Exception e){

                Log.e("Log",e.getMessage(),e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        }



        @Override
        public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH_EXTERNAL, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE + SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
                try{
                    onCreate(db);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Log",e.getMessage(),e.fillInStackTrace());
                }
                return db;
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Log",e.getMessage(),e.fillInStackTrace());
                if(db!=null)
                    db.close();
            }
            return db;
        }// End of getWritableDatabase()



**Inserting  and Retrieving data from database:-**


public void insertIntoTable(String[] userName,int[] score)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            for (int i = 0; i < beatID.length; i++) {
                cv.put("UserName",userName[i]);
                cv.put("Score",score[i]);

                db.insert("TableName", "UserName",
                        cv);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
    }


public void getUserNamePswd(){
        Cursor c = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try{
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();     
            c = db.rawQuery("Select UserName,Score from TableName",null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            String[] username = new String[c.getCount()];
            int[] score = new int[c.getCount()];            
            int counter = 0;
            c.moveToFirst();
            while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            username[counter] = c.getString(0);
            score[counter] = c.getInt(1);
            c.moveToNext();
            counter++;
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Log", e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            return null;      
        }finally{
            c.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As the `/asset` directory is **read only** (because android .apk file is read-only) so you can't write anything in asset folder file, you have to first copy that sqlite database file into your application's internal storage `/data/data/<package_name>/databases` directory then you can modify your database file..

1. Copy your pre-populated sqlite database file into `data/data/<package_name>/databases directory`,
2. Open that database file (from /databases/ directory) in your sqlite database helper class..
3. Perform insert, update or select operation on that database..

Comment: well friends i did this way and i read the data from the that file into my application.but i am getting problem in writing to this file.plz give me any inserting techniques to insert into this file.i have written the code for the reading from this file .no issue with reading just need to insert .

Comment: yes,then after getting user name and score need to show it on to the List view.so i thought as to inserting the data to data base file and then show it in to the listview.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy database file from asset and paste in /data/data/''/databases/ folder

```
private static String DB_NAME = "QuotesData.db";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/[PACKAGE NAME]/databases/";
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

In Above code : Replace [PACKAGE NAME ] with your package name.

Comment: i have this code with me i have idea on how to read from it as is googled .but i am not getting any idea on how to insert in to this type of files.need code for the insertion operation of this given example.i want to put only username and score to the data base file