# data does not inserting into the prebuilt database

Tags: android, sqlite

[Here is my project](http://www.mediafire.com/?ffo1tfas72ygna9)

Here I want to insert something into my database. I also used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700262/how-to-insert-data-into-the-database-file-which-is-in-the-assets-folder)
as reference but tht goes in vain.

But here is the error-log I have.

```
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crews.databaseproto.activity/com.crews.databaseproto.activity.DatabaseProtoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)  
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:555)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at com.crews.databaseproto.activity.DataBaseHelper.insertData(DataBaseHelper.java:153)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at com.crews.databaseproto.activity.DatabaseProtoActivity.onCreate(DatabaseProtoActivity.java:37)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-04 16:53:20.272: E/AndroidRuntime(18378):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for the wrong link

Comment: `database not open` -- Did you open a connection to your database before attempting to insert your data?

Comment: yes i did @George look here myDbHelper.openDataBase();
   myDbHelper.insertData(10,"kaushik", "dhor sala", 22.332322332, 88.2323232); in the DatabaseProtoActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase()
```

no need to over-ride this function. Just use the in-build one.

Also,

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

change the modes in which you opened the DB to write to.

Answer (score 1):

Open the DataBase  as follows

```
 SqliteDatabase db=myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
 cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,10);
 cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,"Kaushik");
 cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,"dhor sala");
 cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,22.332322332);
 cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,88.2323232);
 float row id=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is inserted but Because DeptId is Primary key it is giving error to insert Duplicate data in table Dept.

```
 05-05 00:01:09.783: E/Database(1011):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
```

Comment: I am Saying that your data is inserted properly once but because by code you are trying to inserting same data in the table and because DeptId is primary your DB throws Exception.

Comment: DeptId ? how come thre is no such field? n by the way food_joint_id is the primary key here.but I am not inserting any data on tht field.

Comment: Check your code Uploaded on MediaFire here is the SQL Query CREATE TABLE Dept (DeptID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , DeptName TEXT)