# How to populate Database from path file in API 28 (Android 9)

Tags: java, android, database, path, android-version

I know people asked for this question already. I followed the same answers which accepted by the user [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700262/how-to-insert-data-into-the-database-file-which-is-in-the-assets-folder). It worked fine for other Android versions but except Android 9.

```
private static String DB_NAME = "QuotesData.db";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/[PACKAGE NAME]/databases/";
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

I'm getting null exception like no such table found.

**Logcat**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.in22labs.neet, PID: 23832
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.in22labs.neet/com.in22labs.neet.Quiz.Exammode}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Technical (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Id FROM Technical WHERE TopicId ='Che1'
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Can anyone help? It perfectly works with other Android versions (Even in Android 8.1).

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exammode);
    init();

    Intent receivedIntent = this.getIntent();
    subject = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("subject");
    topicid = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("TopicId");
    Log.e("Test","Exam page Created");

    ConnectionDetector cd=new ConnectionDetector(Exammode.this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("NEET");
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    dbt = new DataBaseTechnical(Exammode.this);

    getQno=dbt.getQuesNo(topicid);
    InsertQuestionRandom();
```

**InsertQuestionRandom method**

```
 private void InsertQuestionRandom() {
    System.out.println("Before shuffling, ArrayList contains : " +getQno);
    Collections.shuffle(getQno);
    System.out.println("After shuffling, ArrayList contains : " + getQno);
    //Toast.makeText(myContext, (CharSequence) arrayList,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for(int i=0; i<20 ;i++)
    {
        int Shuff=getQno.get(i);
        dbt.SelectQuestSet(Shuff);
    }
}
```

Comment: @blackapps Done. hope its clear now and yeah... can you help me?

Comment: @blackapps my Bad! hope now its readable.

Comment: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Technical`

Comment: @blackapps this exception occurs only in android 28 as i mentioned before ... there is table Technical which is readable in other API versions inclucding API 26 and 27

Comment: You never named an sql exception. You talked about null exception.

Comment: Your code to copy a file from assets has nothing to do with that exception. You better post the code that throws that exception.

Comment: @blackapps i specified null exception like no table found. Anyways i posted the entire code where the exception is pointed

Comment: copyDataBase() is nowhere called. We dont know what DataBaseTechnical would be. You are not telling which statement causes the exception.